# Algebra - Absolute Value $\to$ Standard form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

**Problem.** Given that $x < 5$, rewrite $5x - |x - 5|$ without using absolute value signs.

I get that for positive $x$, this is $4x-5$ (this is because $|x-5|=5-x$, thus simplifying to $5x-5-x=4x-5$), but how does one deal with the negative case?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note $5x - (5 - x) = 5x - 5 + x = 6x - 5$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Since the absolute value signs are around $x - 5$, it's this value, not $x$, which is important regarding it being positive, $0$ or negative. In particular, the definition of [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) for real numbers is

$$|z| = \begin{cases}
z & \text{ if } \; z \ge 0 \\
-z & \text{ if } \; z \lt 0
\end{cases}
\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This is true for $z$ being any real constant, or it being any real value expression, such as $x - 5$. Next, from what you're given, subtracting $5$ from both sides gives

$$x \lt 5 \implies x - 5 \lt 0 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Thus, using \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$|x - 5| = -(x - 5) = -x + 5 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

The expression to rewrite then becomes

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
5x - |x - 5| & = 5x - (-x + 5) \\
& = 5x + x - 5 \\
& = 6x - 5
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Answer (score 0):

Think of it bro. In any case for z<5, x-5 would turn into 5-x. Considering about the case, the brackets would be used because the negative sign is on the whole of x-5. Now the answer should look clear. By calculating, the answer would come 6x-5. Thanks for the cooperation. Sorry if I misunderstood where you are facing problem in the question.

Comment: I know, I know, I made the dumb mistake of not including parentheses. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If $t$ is a real number, $|t|$ is the distance of $t$ from zero on the real number line.  Thus,
$$|t| = \begin{cases}
           t & \text{if $t \geq 0$}\\
           -t & \text{if $t < 0$}
           \end{cases}
$$

Let $t = x - 5$.  Observe that $x - 5 \geq 0 \iff x \geq 5$.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
|x - 5| & = \begin{cases}
            x - 5 & \text{if $x \geq 5$}\\
            -(x - 5) & \text{if $x < 5$}\\
            \end{cases}\\
        & = \begin{cases}
            x - 5 & \text{if $x \geq 5$}\\
           -x + 5 & \text{if $x < 5$}\\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
5x - |x - 5| & = \begin{cases}
                 5x - (x - 5) && \text{if $x \geq 5$}\\
                 5x - (-x + 5) && \text{if $x < 5$}\\
                 \end{cases}\\
             & = \begin{cases}
                 4x + 5 && \text{if $x \geq 5$}\\
                 6x - 5 && \text{if $x < 5$}
                 \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Notice that you made an error in the case when $x - 5 > 0$.